# A universal mod-rewrite htaccess file for my script

Tags: windows, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-configuration

I'm writing a script that (I hope) will be widely distributed and I want make sure that it will work on as many servers as possible out of the box.

This script will require an .htaccess file but I've learned some htaccess files are not very portable.

The htaccess needs to do a simple redirect, like so:

```
http://example.com/dir/string

Redirect to...

http://example.com/dir/index.php?string
```

What would a 'universal' .htaccess file look like that would work on all windows and linux servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
# if the file|folder exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php?$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm running LAMP with WampServer

Comment: I changed it a bit based on my currently working file and I fixed it. Now will this also work on windows servers?